# Remove title bar from GNOME but keep window controls

Tags: gnome, window, titlebar, window-control

I want to remove the title bar from maximized GNOME applications, but every extension that does this also removes the window controls. How do I get rid of the title and keep the controls?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Pixel Saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/) gnome extension. It hides the title bar and shows the window control options on the right of top panel